# classnotfoundexception on running maven web application in tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

recently I wrote a basic web application with only index.jsp and a simple servlet, here's the code:
index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello W!</h1>
    <form action="Hello.do">
        <p>Wprowadź imię:   </p>
        <input type="text" name="imie"/>
        <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

in web.xml there is a fragment linking Hello.do to servlet HelloServlet.java:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.helion.jeeweb.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Hello.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and of course servlet in package pl.helion.jeeweb.
But when I launch the application, fill the form and click OK, I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class pl.helion.jeeweb.HelloServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
...
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.helion.jeeweb.HelloServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
...
```

so what's wrong? 
and by the way, sorry for my english and thanks for help;]

Comment: teh first thing i would do is look in tomcat's webapps directory and check that your application is there and has the correct form.  then i would look at the jar files that you find there to make sure that the class is present.  your english is fine.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have this packaged as a war and are dropping it in the tomcat webapps directory?

Comment: Have you checked that the class given in web.xml pl.helion.jeeweb.HelloServlet really exists? (May be a typo?)

Comment: ok, I see where's problem. in pl/helion/jeeweb I have HelloServlet.java, not class. So what exactly is wrong with settings? something in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had a bad folder structure. By default package and servlet were in folder resources, all I had to do was to rename it to java